# SAX parsing Application working fine on android2.2 but giving exception in ICS

Tags: android, parsing, sax, android-virtual-device, saxparser

im trying to implement SAXParsing... I've been getting exceptions when i run my app on my phone but when i run it on an android 2.2 AVD , the app works fine.
please look into my code.
I've deleted the URL that i'm parsing 'cause i dont feel comfortable showing it in public.

```
public class ZodiacXMLParsing extends Activity{


String mainURL="http://www.myURL/zodiac.xml";
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle zodiac) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(zodiac);
    setContentView(R.layout.zodiacxmlparsing);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    try{
        URL website=new URL(mainURL);
        SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();

        HandlingXMLStuff handle=new HandlingXMLStuff();
        xr.setContentHandler(handle);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));

        String information=handle.getInformation();
        tv.setText(information);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(ZodiacXMLParsing.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

public class HandlingXMLStuff extends DefaultHandler{

```
XMLDataCollected info=new XMLDataCollected();

public String getInformation(){
    return info.set();
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(localName.equals("aries")){
        String aries=attributes.getValue("data");
        info.get(aries);

    }
}
```

}

public class XMLDataCollected {

```
String contents;

public void get(String z){
    contents=z;
}

public String set(){
    return contents;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the error logs

Comment: The assumption by user1990572 about Asynctask is valid. But paste your logs too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an AsyncTask. Since you haven't posted the error log, I assume that is your problem.